# NSArray with storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib, uistoryboard

I am trying to convert the code listed below to be able to be used with `Storyboards`. I am using `Xcode 5.0.2` currently. If you can help it would be appreciated.

```
 {
      NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Main" owner:self options:nil];
      cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
 }
```

Comment: Where is this code? What is in the `Main` NIB? Is this trying to convert the whole app from NIB to storyboard?

Comment: @Wain I think he's trying to do the old way of loading a table view cell with preset layout via a nib.

Comment: @Wain Main NIB was the old view that showed a table view and other various other items/objects. I am needing to have the code to reference my storyboard (the storyboard is named main.storyboard) instead of the NIB called Main. What do you mean by "Where is the code"? and what do you mean by is this trying to convert the whole app from NIB to storyboard?

Comment: I mean you set no scope for the question. Changing a main NIB to a main storyboard is different to moving a view controller NIB into a storyboard.

Comment: @ZaneF Ok, so the code you provided is from the old UITableViewCell Nib trick, but you want to set your root from nib to storyboard?  Completely different things.  You can set that in your target under general, deployment info, then main interface.

Comment: @Derek Its fine, what you answered below worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do this anymore with storyboards.  All you need to do is copy and paste the content of the cell nib into a new cell in a table view with dynamic prototypes.

1. Drag a new Table View Cell into a Table View.  Make sure to set your Table View to dynamic prototypes.
2. Set the cell's identifier and load that the same as you would programmatically.
3. Copy and paste the content from your nib into the new cell.